# When running php's msg_get_queue(), is there any way to specify the group ownership of the queue?

Tags: php, queue, semaphore

The 2nd argument to msg_get_queue is `int $permissions = 0666`, which could be set to `0660` to restrict use of the queue to the current group.

Is there any way to specify which of a user's groups is the current group before calling this command, without using elevated privileges?

In my case, I want the queue to be available to group `apache`, so it can be accessed by user `apache` and other members of that group.  However, this only works if user `apache` is the first one to call the method, and that can't be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will work to wrap the launching command with `sg`, for example if the `readqueue.php` script calls `msg_get_queue()` one could run:

```
sg apache 'php readqueue.php'
```

From the man page:

```
NAME
   sg - execute command as different group ID

SYNOPSIS
   sg [-] [group [-c ] command]

DESCRIPTION
   The sg command works similar to newgrp but accepts a command. The
   command will be executed with the /bin/sh shell...
```